# Binding a Silverlight control function to my view model

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

Okay, so I'm using these custom controls. Don't worry about that part though, the question doesn't relate to their working.

The control in question is a grid (like the regular grid), and it comes with a BeginInsert function, which is a short cut to adding a new item to the list.

Now what I want is to have access to that method in my view model. At the moment I do have this, but it goes through my XAML code behind, which I don't want - I'd like for it to go straight from the XAML to the view model.

Here's how it goes at the moment:

```
((UserViewModel)Resources["usersViewModel"]).HydUsersGridBeginInsert = () => this.GridViewData.BeginInsert();
```

This code is in the XAML code behind. HydUsersGridBeginInsert is of type Action and sits in the view model. GridViewData is the name of the grid.

So how can I get this out of my code behind and directly into my view model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use event to command with parameters.

```
 <Button Content="Add">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AddClickCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </Button>
```

here namespace "i" refers to xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
and

xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4"

this is galasoft MVVM light tool kit ( google to download)

Add similar code in viewModel like

```
 public ICommand AddClickCommand { get; set; }

 AddClickCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((e) =>
 {
      this.BeginInsert();
 });
```

### hope this will work for you.

I thought You will get started from my answer.

what i wanted to convince you is

```
    <your:YourGrid x:Name="yourGrid">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
             <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GridLoadedCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </your:YourGrid>
```

All you need to do is in LoadedCommand.

```
 YourGrid grid ;
 public ICommand GridLoadedCommand { get; set; }

 GridLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventHandler>((s, e) =>
 {
     grid = (YourGrid) s;
 });

 public ICommand AddClickCommand { get; set; }

 AddClickCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((e) =>
 {
      grid.BeginInsert();
 });


 Now what you say about this.
```

Comment: I thank you for your comment, particularly because you explained what things I needed. When I was first learning, I could have used something like that.

That said, I'm afraid the question has not been answered here. What you have shown me is how to map an event directly to my code behind. This I already know how to do (using the shown method, incidentally). The grid I'm using has functionality attached to it. The 'BeginInsert' function I show in my example actually does something. I don't know what it does, but it does something. It is this method I want to call from my VM.

Comment: That second solution gets us closer, but a problem still remains. If I'm in a view model, I don't want user elements tied to it. So I can't have a user element declared inside the view model. Aside that, it's okay... but it is a deal breaker.

Comment: If you don't want a ref in your ViewModel to anything in the View, you need to use messaging, a behavior, or you inject a service of some type that has access to what you need.

Comment: if the Grid you are using doing some thing and you do not want to have reference of it in VM, then you got to call it by messaging. or use MEF framework. IMHO either way you will have reference to grid before calling BeginInsert() in your VM

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to be able to call BeginEdit on the grid from within your ViewModel?  There are a few ways to do this:

1) You can use Messaging, like the one in MVVM-Light's framework.  In your code behind you would subscribe to an event, BeginEdit, and in your ViewModel you would Publish the BeginEdit event.

2) You could create a behavior, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/ViewModelTree.aspx) is a similar example where a node on a TreeView is expanded by using a behavior.

So, in the example, you can set a variable, IsBeginEdit and the behavior will fire, calling BeginEdit on the GridView.  [source](https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/cmdemo/src) MiscView/MiscViewModel

Behavior:

In the example source I listed, I'm using Caliburn Micro and by naming the button element x:Name="BeginEdit" CM will automagically bind that to my BeginEdit method.  If you're using Mvvm-Light you can use EventToCommand.

```
<Button Content="BeginEdit">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding BeginEdit, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </Button>

[Description("BeginEdit")]
    public class BeginEditBehavior : TargetedTriggerAction<RadGridView>
    {
        private RadGridView _radGridView;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            _radGridView = (RadGridView) (AssociatedObject);
        }

        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            _radGridView.BeginEdit();
        }
    }

View: 

<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBeginEdit, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                                <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                                    <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding IsBeginEdit}"
                                                            RightOperand="True" />
                                </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                            </ei:ConditionBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <framework:BeginEditBehavior />
                    </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
```

ViewModel:

```
private bool _isBeginEdit;
        public bool IsBeginEdit
        {
            get { return _isBeginEdit; }
            set
            {
                _isBeginEdit = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsBeginEdit);
            }
        }

        public void BeginEdit()
        {
            IsBeginEdit = true;
        }
```

3) And probably not the best way, you could store a reference to your View in your ViewModel.  Caliburn Micro, as an example, gives you a way to access your View GetView() from within your ViewModel, then you could get a reference to your grid and call BeginEdit().

I like option 2 but 1 works just as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first option please?

Comment: I'll put an example together.

Comment: Thanks. I read through the link you gave me for the second option... to be honest I found it a bit confusing. Well, a lot confusing.

Comment: Hi Derek. Perhaps you could do me a favour and explain the process of the behaviour in English? I mean... the behaviour activates based on the state of the IsBeginEdit changed... but what causes it to change? Hopefully you can help me make sense of this. For the record, I didn't know behaviors at all before seeing this. I have since followed a tutorial to create a simple one, but this is quite above that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By naming the button BeginEdit, Caliburn Micro auto binds it to the method.  If you're using MVVM-Light, it's the same as EventToCommand.  Tech. the button implements ICommand so you could use that also.